# Where should i add my method for noInternetConnection? Android

Tags: android, internet-connection

It is all working and i have added my method to check if there is internet connection, and if there isn't change activity. But it is changing activity immediately before loading progress bar. Where should i add this method so first progress bar is loaded and if there is no internet connection, change activity.

Also if anyone have some suggestion about this checking internet connection, i would appricieate any answer.

**This is my activity where i'm using that method:**

```
public class ListaPreporuka extends AppCompatActivity {
// Log tag
private static final String TAG = ListaPreporuka.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://www.nadji-ekipu.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/movies.txt";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private static String Title ="title";
private static String bitmap ="thumbnailUrl";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_preporuka);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);   
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica);

    Intent newActivity2=new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity2);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Učitavanje...");
    pDialog.show();      

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            final JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                        

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    noInternet();

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) { 
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                    .getText().toString();

            bitmap = ((Movie)movieList.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaPreporuka.this, MoviesSingleActivity.class);    
            intent.putExtra(Title, name);
            intent.putExtra("images", bitmap);
            intent.putExtra("Year", movieList.get(position).getYear());             
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
            }
        });

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

//WHERE SHOULD I ADD THIS METHOD FOR MAKING MY ACTIVITY SHOW FIRST PROGRESS BAR AND IF THERE IS NO INTERNET CONNECTION, SHOW ANOTHER ACTIVITY
private void noInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null) {
        if (!info.isConnected()) {
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListaPreporuka.this, NoConnection.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making some http request. So you want to chek if there is internet connection available right?
So first put a check if internet connection is available.

Wherever you are doing your other operations ..

```
if(internet connection is present){
     //make http request;
}else{
     // display appropriate message and switch to your new activity
}
```

Comment: in your onCreate(), below your pDialog.show() call, if you want to display, progress bar first and then check for internet connection. 
However, i wouldn't show progress dialog unnecessarily first before making any call. Its better to first check for internet connction and if present , then so the work.
Also, make sure you dismiss the progress dialog before switching to next activity, otherwise your app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your method in the same place but with some delay, if you want simple answer. Something like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

But, I think, you should better use this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#show%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29) to show dialog:

```
public static ProgressDialog show (Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener cancelListener)
```

Implement DialogInterface.OnCancelListener, call your intent with transition to the new activity in onCancel callback of OnCancelListener.

And use pDialog.cancel() in else statement of noInternet() method.

Comment: I'm little confuse here. I'm already set dialog and i would like to show that dialog first and then if there is no internet connection, change activity like i initialize my method.

Comment: Regarding Handler example, you can just include Handler code instead of your noInternet() call in onCreate() method.

Like that:
`final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
    noInternet();
  }
}, 100);`

System will call run() method in Handler with stated delay so your views will have time to render.

Comment: Okay. And in run method to call class Intent for changing activity if there is noInternet. And one more question. Where exatcly should i put handler? Before json or after?

Comment: Because Handler is asynchronous and your call with json in AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq) is asynchronous too, as I understand. So you can place Handler whereever you want in onCreate(). You can put it instead of noInternet() call in onCreate().

Comment: your method is working, but when there is Internet connection it's still changing activity like there is no internet connection.

Comment: You should use your noInternet() code to check it properly and change activity only if there is no connection.